# How to change the color of active tab ? (tab is custom)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation in RN v 0.46.1 project

I have used customTabs from example directory of react-navigation.

I want to change the color of the tab when active .

I've tried to pass ans use navigationOptions but no success.

Also , Tabs are displayed at top , I want them at bottom.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AppRegistry,  Button,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View } from "react-native";
import { createNavigator,
        createNavigationContainer,
        TabRouter,
        addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation'
import Chats from './Chats'
import Contacts from './Contacts'

const MyNavScreen = ({ navigation, banner }) => (
  <ScrollView>
    <Text>banner</Text>
    <Button
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.goBack(null);
      }}
      title="Go back"
    />
  </ScrollView>
);

const MySettingsScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
  <MyNavScreen banner="Settings Screen" navigation={navigation} />
);

const CustomTabBar = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { routes } = navigation.state;
  return (
    <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
      {routes.map(route => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate(route.routeName)}
          style={styles.tab}
          key={route.routeName}
        >
          <Text>{route.routeName}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

const CustomTabView = ({ router, navigation }) => {
  const { routes, index } = navigation.state;
  const ActiveScreen = router.getComponentForState(navigation.state);
  const routeNav = addNavigationHelpers({
    ...navigation,
    state: routes[index],
  });
  const routeOptions = router.getScreenOptions(routeNav, 'tabBar');
console.log(routeOptions.headerTintColor);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CustomTabBar navigation={navigation} />
      <ActiveScreen
        navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
          ...navigation,
          state: routes[index],
        })}
      />
    </View>
  );
};


const CustomTabRouter = TabRouter(
  {
    Friends: {
      screen: Chats,
      path: '',
    },
    Status: {
      screen: Contacts,
      path: 'notifications',
    },
    Other: {
      screen: MySettingsScreen,
      path: 'settings',
    },
  },
  {

    initialRouteName: 'Friends',

  },
);

const CustomTabs = createNavigationContainer(
  createNavigator(CustomTabRouter)(CustomTabView)
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : 0,
  },
  tabContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 48,
  },
  tab: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    margin: 4,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor:'white'
  },
});

export default CustomTabs;

AppRegistry.registerComponent('awsm', () => CustomTabs);
```

Comment: can you get active tab's `routeName`?

Comment: @JigarShah yes I can get that .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910540/react-navigation-how-to-change-tabbar-color-based-on-current-tab/46090295#46090295

Answer (score 2):

Compare the active tab's `routeName` in map and add style like

```
style={[(this.props.activeRouteName == route.routeName) ? styles.activeTab : styles.tab]}
```

For styling tabs at bottom you can use `ScrollView` in parent view and then your tabs so,  it will be something like this

```
<View style={flex:1}>
    <ScrollView>
        // your page content
    </ScrollView>
   <Tabs/>
</View>
```

By using scrollview you will be able to force the tabs at bottom.

Comment: awesome, its not exactly the answer but approach is perfect ! Ty , it worked for me. :)

Comment: any idea for styling them to bottom ?

Comment: Sorry,  not sure what do you mean by styling them to bottom

Comment: I mean that now they are visible at top of the screen , what if I want them at bottom of screen. I have tried but they just vanish from the screen.

Comment: I have updated my answer to get tabs at bottom but I would suggest to place at top if not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you achieve what you want with the default `TabNavigator` ?

In the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#TabNavigatorConfig) you can pass a `TabBarComponent` to the TabNavigator and set `tabBarPosition - position of the tab bar, can be 'top' or 'bottom'` to `bottom` so your tabBar will be at the bottom.

If you still want to do all that yourself, I guess :

- To align the TabBar on the bottom, you could put `{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 0 }` on the TabBar style
- To change the color of your focused Tab, you could do:

`const CustomTabBar = ({ navigation }) => {
      const { routes, index } = navigation.state;
      const isFocused = routes[index].routeName == route.routeName; // Not totally sure about the condition there, but you get the idea?
      return (
        <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
          {routes.map(route => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate(route.routeName)}
              style={[styles.tab, isFocused ? styles.focusedTab : null]}
              key={route.routeName}
            >
              <Text>{route.routeName}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </View>
      );
    };`

?